# Convention for order of coordinates when defining a rectangle

Tags: image-processing, conventions, convention

Given a coordinate system (e.g. pixel grid), you can define a rectangle with four numbers: two x-axis values (sides of rectangle) and two y-axis values (top/bottom of rectangle). My question is, is there a widely used and/or accepted convention for what order these values should be? What order would be **the most familiar** to those in the image processing world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "convention" as different uses might need different representations.
FWIW, rectangles are *usually* defined in one of two ways:

1. Origin (x,y) + Size (width x height)
2. Top Left (x0,y0) + Bottom-Right (x1, y1)

That being said, there are many permutations of these and often class methods will provide conversions and multiple constructors might support multiple initializations.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your distinction between "convention" and "what is usual"?

Comment: "Convention" means an *agreed upon* way to do things - there is usually just one. "Usually" means what you might commonly see in various independent APIs - there can be a variety of flavors.  
In math the convention is (x,y) and not (y,x) but matrix notation is (row (y), column(y)). In math Y is by convention up, in image processing Y is usually down...

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!